# Compute $ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan^n x \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Compute $$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan^n x \ dx$$

Using reduction formula I got $$I_n = \int_0^{\pi/2} \tan^n(x) dx = \int_0^{\pi/2} \tan^{n-2}(x) \sec^2(x) dx - \int_0^{\pi/2} \tan^{n-2}(x)dx$$
But I'm not sure how to proceed...

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0%5Epi%2F2+tan+x+dx ... Wolfie says "No" ...

Comment: Yeah, that's why I asked. Got this as a homework from my prof., but I can't really solve it...

Comment: Is $n$ supposed to be an integer?

Comment: It is not specified, but I'm pretty sure it should be an integer @Daniel Fischer

Comment: Change the upper limit to $\frac{\pi}{4}$ & suppose $n$ is an even positive number ... this is much more interesting.

Comment: Anyway, $\tan x$ behaves like $x$ near $0$, and it behaves like $\dfrac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} - x}$ near $\pi/2$, so $\tan^n x$ is improperly Riemann integrable/Lebesgue integrable over $[0,\pi/2]$ if and only if $\lvert n\rvert < 1$.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that, it would be a lot easier, the solution is even here already: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/202418/compute-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-pi-4-tann-x-dx 
but I have to solve this problem or show that it's unsolvable using some nice arguments... @ Donald Splutterwit

Comment: If $n$ assumes real numbers, then the integral converges if and only if $|n| < 1$. In this case, the integral can be computed using beta function identity combined with the Euler reflection formula. For the regime $n \geq 1$, notice that $$\tan x \geq \frac{\sin x}{\frac{\pi}{2} - x}, \qquad x \in [0, \pi/2). $$ This can be used to show the divergence of $I_n$. The regime $n \leq -1$ follows from the identity $I_{-n} = I_n$.

Comment: For n=1 the integral diverges to +$\infty$, then that integral looks to diverge

Comment: Ok, then |n|<1, although it is not specified... I could use a little help with "beta function identity combined with the Euler reflection formula", if you'd be so kind @Sangchul Lee

Comment: It is definitely beyond the usual calculus course, so let me just give you links to them without explanation. Using the [*beta function identity*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties) and the [*Euler's reflection formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#General), we get $$ I_n = \int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^n \theta \cos^{-n}\theta\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}B\left(\frac{1+n}{2},\frac{1-n}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{\sin(\frac{\pi-\pi n}{2})} = \frac{\pi}{2\cos(\frac{\pi n}{2})} $$ when $|n| < 1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan^nxdx= \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\tan^nxdx+\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan^nxdx > \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan x dx = \ln\left(\frac{\sec(\pi/2)}{\sec(\pi/4)}\right) = \infty
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\tan^{n}\pars{x} & 
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ x\ \to\ 0^{+}}{\sim}\,\,\, x^{n}
\\[5mm]
\tan^{n}\pars{x} & = \cot^{n}\pars{{\pi \over 2} - x} = {1 \over \tan^{n}\pars{\pi/2 - x}}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\mrm{as}\ x\ \to\ \pars{\pi/2}^{-}}{\sim}\,\,\,
\pars{{\pi \over 2} - x}^{-n}
\end{align}

> The integral converges whenever $\ds{\verts{\Re\pars{n}} < 1}$.